# import csv in excel

Tags: excel, vba

EDITED 14 may

After a lot of reading I finally understand the basics of VBA. I have created the macro below, but it still isn't working, it won't insert the csv files.
Afte this macro is finished the saved files are all empty. With debug.print I confirmed the string to the files is complete, but still something is missing?

Can anybody help me fix this problem

thanks in advance

```
Sub CSVimporterennaarxlsx()
    'On Error Resume Next
    'declare variable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strpath As String
    Dim fmn As Integer
    Dim lmn As Integer
    Dim csvname As String
    Dim strpathcsvname As String
    'active workbook pathway
    strpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    'ask user for first and last number
    fmn = InputBox("first mouse number")
    lmn = InputBox("last mouse number")
    'einde sub if inputbox is empty
'    If fmn = "" Then
'    MsgBox "No first mouse number"
'    Exit Sub
'    End If
'    If lmn = "" Then
'    MsgBox "No Last mouse number"
'    Exit Sub
'    End If

    'assign variables

    'loop all the files
     For fmn = fmn To lmn
     csvname = "m" & fmn
     strpathcsvname = strpath & "\" & csvname & ".csv"
     'input of csv file
'        ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" + strpathcsvname, _
            Destination:=Range(A1))
'filename without extension
            .Name = csvname
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
            , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
            1, 1)
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
            .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        End With
    Call CsvToXlsx(ByVal csvname, strpath)
    Next fmn
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub

    Sub CsvToXlsx(ByVal csvname, strpath)
    ChDir (strpath & "/verwerkt")
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    csvname = csvname & ".xlsx"
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvname, FileFormat:=51

    End Sub
```

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551353/saving-excel-worksheet-to-csv-files-with-filenameworksheet-name-using-vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just to open the `.csv` file and save it as an `.xls` file

```
Sub CsvToXls (csvname)
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=csvname
  xlsname = Replace(csvname, ".csv",".xls")  
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xlsname , FileFormat:=xlNormal
End Sub
```

then, to iterate for all `.csv` files in a dir

```
Sub AllCsvToXls(dirname)        
    Dim csv As Variant 
    csv = Dir(dirname & "\*.csv")
    While (csv <> "")
      CsvToXls (dirname & "\" & csv)
      csv = Dir
    Wend  
End Sub
```

and finally, invoke it ...

```
AllCsvToXls(ThisWorkbook.Path)
```

Comment: +1 very clean code. I suggest using `.OpenText` method though since OP set `True` for `Comma` and `Tab` delimiters.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering so fast, Is there any source where I can find explanation for the code.

Comment: The code is (in my opinion which is obviously biased because I wrote myself the code) very readable and understandable. If you have trouble with the basic programming structures (`Sub`, `While`) and library functions (`Dir`, `Replace`) it uses, I suggest you to grab a good book on VBA and start studying.

Comment: What is su ? I assume it is an other forum? 
I already bought a book for VBA, So I hope I can solve this problem myself in about a week or so.

Comment: SU = SuperUser ( http:\\superuser.com )

Comment: @PA If been trying to modify my code and to add yours but i have a few questions,with the code u provided. I understand what it does right now. But i don't have a clue how to concatenate the functions. Does it have to be different subs?

Comment: yes, two different subs, and you can place the invoking call as an independent macro.

Comment: @PA after learning a lot I have modified a lot, but still 1 thing doesn't work the new code has been pasted above