# Automatically save certain sheets in workbook to CSV file

Tags: vba, excel

I have found a decent solution [Saving excel worksheet to CSV files with filename+worksheet name using VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551353/saving-excel-worksheet-to-csv-files-with-filenameworksheet-name-using-vb) for saving all worksheets in a workbook as CSV files. However, I would like to be able to modify this code to only save worksheets where the sheet name ends with `_t`.

I am using the following code:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "H:\test\"
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.

End Sub
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Right` or `Instr`-Method on the `worksheet.name` property to get the last characters / check if your searchstring is exisiting.

In your `for each`-loop add the following code:

```
If Right(WS.name, 2) = "_t" Then
  Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
  ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
  ThisWorkbook.Activate        
End if
```

Comment: perfect! thanks for the quick solution. Works as described and as requested.

Comment: if possible, please use the tick to mark the question as answered
and you're welcome :)