# Multi worksheet export one to CSV and autosave with no prompt

Tags: excel, vba, csv

haven't done much with macros but some.  I have searched and found some similar of what I need to do but not exact and wonder if anyone can help.
For work I have a excel workbook with multiple sheets, and one sheet I create a copy and save as CSV because a program we work with will only accept txt or csv format so have to save every time we want to import data.  I am basically looking to have that one data sheet to auto save on a csv file in the folder that will save without the prompt so the program can just auto import the data from it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving excel worksheet to CSV files with filename+worksheet name using VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551353/saving-excel-worksheet-to-csv-files-with-filenameworksheet-name-using-vb) If you don't like prompts you can incorporate `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` somewhere into that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to use of [Worksheet.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx):

> If you don't specify either Before or After, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the copied sheet object that contains the copied Worksheet object. The newly created workbook holds the Application.ActiveWorkbook Property (Excel) property and contains a single worksheet.
>
> The single worksheet retains the Worksheet.Name Property (Excel) and Worksheet.CodeName Property (Excel) properties of the source worksheet.
>
> If the copied worksheet held a worksheet code sheet in a VBA project, that is also carried into the new workbook.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    ' Call your Sub
    CopySheet2CSV ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
End Sub

Sub CopySheet2CSV(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\b036081\NoBackupData\" & ws.Name & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close Savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Capitalize on the fact that `.Copy` conveniently sets `ActiveWorkbook` to the newly created workbook that contains your single sheet.

Save it as csv, close it afterwards, thereby returning to your source worksheet.

**Note:** Don't explicitly turn all prompts off. Instead omit the two standard prompts you get when doing this manually by setting `CreateBackup:=False` when saving and `Savechanges:=False` when closing the csv-workbook.

That way you are still prompted in cases where the file exists or there is an error.

Comment: Did you replace `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")` with your actual table name?