# Opening a csv file in a macro enabed workbook and making changes, saving the cvs file without the macros enabled

Tags: vba, excel, csv, vbscript

I have a .csv file that will be generated frequently and named using timestamp. I need to run a macro in it and update the .csv file. I used this solution [Run Excel Macro from Outside Excel Using VBScript From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line) for running my macro, but my problem is I'm unable to save the .csv file without the macros enabled in it and the changes being saved in it. I have only one sheet of the csv file. Thanks for the help!
This is the code I'm using, (got from that link):

```
   Dim oFSO
   Dim oShell, oExcel, oFile, oSheet
   Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set wb2 = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\.....\PERSONAL.XLSB") 'Specify     foldername here 

   oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

   For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder("D:\..\Output1\").Files
      If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "csv" Then
 
         With oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, True, , , , True, , , , False, , False)
         oExcel.Run wb2.Name & "!final1"
         
         End With
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551353/saving-excel-worksheet-to-csv-files-with-filenameworksheet-name-using-vb have a look here

Answer (score 0):

a csv file is a text file. open it with a text editor and you will see.

it has no functionality to have a macro embedded inside it.

you need to have the macro inside an excel file, and have it do the work that you need

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply!. I'm trying to run the macro from the personal workbook and I think "With oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, True, , , , True, , , , False, , False)" opens my .csv file runs the macro in it. If I use oExcel.Save , during runtime it is asking me to save the edited file. I need this to be saved automatically.